# How to display the result of the query?

Tags: node.js, express, node-oracledb

I use this library [oracle-sage](https://github.com/FoundationMedicineInc/oracle-sage). I have a request to create a user. The request itself is working. But there is such a problem that the displayed result looks like this:

```
{
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
}
```

How can display the created entry in JSON format as a result?

```
module.exports.create = async function (req, res) {
    const candidate = await User.findOne(
        { LOGIN: req.body.LOGIN }
    )

    if (candidate) {
        res.status(409).json({
            message: 'This login is already taken. Try another one.'
        })
    } else {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        const password = await req.body.PASSWORD
        const user = User.create({
            LOGIN: req.body.LOGIN,
            EMAIL: req.body.PHONE,
            PASSWORD: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        });
        try {
            res.status(201).json(user)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Model.create` returns a `Promise` object, not the user which is what you’re expecting. This is what the JSON that you’re seeing is—a promise object. You need to wait for that Promise to finish and then extract the return value. You can do this using the `await` keyword like you did in a few other lines.  Which means that you should be calling:

```
res.status(201).json(user)
```

Edit: it doesn’t seem like getting the created value is part of the API docs and I can’t reproduce locally. 
You can store the value in a variable and return that.

```
const userObj = {
    LOGIN: req.body.LOGIN,
    EMAIL: req.body.PHONE,
    PASSWORD: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
};
const user = User.create(userObj);
try {
    res.status(201).json(userObj)
```

Comment: Nope, now this result comes out: `{
    "rowsAffected": 1
}`

Comment: @user11277006 ah yes, this is because your code is now correct but the return value of mongoose create is telling you how your change affected the database. I have updated my answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: @user11277006 hmmm it looks like it’s possible that the library you’re using, oracle-sage, doesn’t support getting this value back from the DB immediately. I can’t find it anywhere in their docs. Is there any reason why you need what’s stored exactly? If you just care about sending back what you passed into the create function, you can just store that as a variable and send that back to the user.

Comment: Ok, i'm then try to do as you say

Comment: @user11277006 you can see my edit for the minor refactor.

Comment: Thanks you very much